# Regex to seach a exactly string in csv

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex for using in javascript to check if "is" keyword exists

```
is, a, line // true
this, is, a, line // true
this, is // true
this, is a, line //false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the sub-string `is` preceeded by start or the line boundary or comma and followed by end of the line boundary or comma with zero or more spaces in-between.

```
string.match(/(?:^|,)\s*is\s*(?:,|$)/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qI2rS2/2)

Comment: @dandavis nooooo, this `[,$]` would match a literall dollar symbol or comma. Special meaning for `$` should get lost inside a char class.

Comment: that's why it was faster :p , time for some sleep... `

Answer (score 1):

Split on commas and find the `is` in the resulting array:

```
function has_is(str) {
  return str.split(/,\s*/) . indexOf('is') !== -1;
}

has_is("is, a, line") // true
has_is("this, is, a, line") // true
has_is("this, is") // true
has_is("this, is a, line") //false
```